# Getting an error Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error | null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web3js

I am fairly new to typescript so I am getting an error which say Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Error | null' and i can't understand why am i getting that. How do I solve this?

```
export function subscribeToAccount(
  web3: Web3,
  callback: (error: Error | null, account: string | null) => any
) {
  const id = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      callback(null, accounts[0]);
    } catch (error) {
      callback(error, null);
    }
  }, 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(id);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is caused by this line:

```
callback(error, null);
```

The type of `error` from `catch (error)` is `unknown`, and you specified that `callback` function accepts `Error | null` as its first parameter, hence why the error.

Read more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#use-unknown-catch-variables)

---

#### Easy, but not recommended fix

Set `strict` value to `false` on your `tsconfig` file

---

#### Another easy, but better way

Explicitly specify the `error` type to `any`

```
try {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  callback(null, accounts[0]);
} catch (error: any) {
  callback(error, null);
}
```

---

#### Best way

Do a type checking inside the catch

```
try {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  callback(null, accounts[0]);
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof Error ) {
    callback(error, null);
  } else {
    // handle
  }
}
```